# sql: max value by 2 columns in another table

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables and for every id in the first table I need to find max value in the date_2 column that would be lower than a value in the date_1 column.

Tables:

table 1

| id | date_1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2020 |
| 1 | 11.01.2020 |
| 2 | 02.11.2020 |
| 2 | 02.12.2020 |
| 3 | 12.12.2020 |
| 3 | 31.01.2021 |

table 2

| id | date_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 30.12.2019 |
| 1 | 05.01.2020 |
| 2 | 01.11.2020 |
| 2 | 30.10.2020 |
| 3 | 10.11.2020 |
| 3 | 31.12.2020 |

outcome needed:

| id | date_1 | max(date_2) within id,date_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01.01.2020 | 30.12.2019 |
| 1 | 11.01.2020 | 05.01.2020 |
| 2 | 02.11.2020 | 01.11.2020 |
| 2 | 02.12.2020 | 01.11.2020 |
| 3 | 12.12.2020 | 10.11.2020 |
| 3 | 31.01.2021 | 31.12.2020 |

appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

you could rank each row (I'm doing it here with row_number() function) then match on the id and the ranking.

```
with t1 as (select id, date_1,
              row_number() over (partion by id order by date1) as rn
         from table1),
     t2 as (select id, date_2,
            row_number() over (partion by id order by date2) as rn
     from table2 ),
     select id, date1, date2
     from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty much write a simple correlated query using *exists* that mirrors the English narrative:

```
select id, (   
  select Max(date_2)          /* find max value in the date_2 column */
  from t2 
  where t2.id = t1.id         /* for every id in the first table */
    and t2.date_2 < t1.date_1 /* lower than a value in the date_1 column */
) as "max(date_2) within id,date_1"
from t1;
```